# Working on a certain column after importing data from a file

Tags: import, data

I'm trying to import a file with 2 columns, in TSV format.

Something like this:

```
time distance
1    25
2    43
3    43
4    54
5    65
6    67 
7    68
8    23
9    99
10   35
```

And I want to do certain things to column 2, such as multiply by 2 or do the difference between the elements.

So, I was trying something like:

```
testing = Import["timedistance.dat"]//TableForm

testing[All, 2]
```

And "testing[All, 2]" gives me the following error: "Part::partw: Part 2 of {}"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: //TableForm puts the value of testing as a displayed table and not an array.

Comment: removing //TableForm and doing "testing = Import["timedistance.dat", "Table"]" gives me the same error. How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Import["timedistance.dat"]  all by itself.  Then, consider something like Transpose[testing][[All]][[2]].

Comment: Doesn't work also. Gives two errors:

1. Transpose::nmtx : The first two levels of the one-dimensional list cannot be transposed.

2. Part:partw: Part 2 of transpose does not exist.

Comment: @MattiasDam not sure what you did differently from what I did.  I created a file identical to the one you have, imported it per the method I suggested, and did the Transpose to easily grab column 2.  But, with Mathematica there are probably a half-dozen other ways to do it better.  I suggest you verify that the array you get from the Import (only) is 10 rows of 2 elements (two columns).  Use Dimensions[testing].  Look at the data.

Comment: @MattiasDam, do you know about `Dataset`? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how the data is imported first.
Using the data provided in the question.

```
testing = Import["sample.tsv"]
(*{{"time distance"}, {"1    25"}, {"2    43"}, {"3    43"}, {"4    \
54"}, {"5    65"}, {"6    67 "}, {"7    68"}, {"8    23"}, {"9    \
99"}, {"10   35"}}*)
```

You can see that the data is imported as a single text per record.
Importing with the "table" option.

```
testing = Import["sample.tsv", "Table"]
(*{{"time", "distance"}, {1, 25}, {2, 43}, {3, 43}, {4, 54}, {5, 
  65}, {6, 67}, {7, 68}, {8, 23}, {9, 99}, {10, 35}}*)
```

Now the data is amenable for computation.

```
title = First@testing; testing=Rest@testing;
{#[[1]],  #[[2]]^2} & /@ testing
(*{{1, 625}, {2, 1849}, {3, 1849}, {4, 2916}, {5, 4225}, {6, 4489}, {7, 
  4624}, {8, 529}, {9, 9801}, {10, 1225}}*)
```

Using version 10 functionality

```
testing = SemanticImport["sample.tsv"]
```

[image]

```
ds[All, Append[#, "function1" -> (2 #distance)] &]
```

[image]